# Boot fails After installing Windows 10 over Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, grub2, windows-10, grubrescue, boot-repair

I installed Win10 over Ubuntu 16. But,after successful installation when rebooted, My PC **stuck at Grub cmd**.

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu in other partition so it would automatically repair Grub.
But it didn't done any help either.

Please suggest.

*my system is Lenovo IP320*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Boot-Repair**

Everytime when my Bootloader gets corrupted, in general with the help of microsoft, i boot the system with a 1gb usb stick containing a Lubuntu version. Than i follow the instructions here [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

In general the default settings work fine.

I hope this helps you somehow.